# how to update Missed Call count when missed call viewed?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I have app that show call logs, and shows count of miss call which is never viewed. Now i want whenever user see miss calls in my app, it should reset the count of miss call in mine and native too.

To get count i used  following query

```
mContentResolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                "type = 3 AND new = 1", null, strOrder);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The column `new=1` is used to indicate missed as you have already posted in your question.

When user views the call in your app you should set `new=0` using `mContentResolver.update()`